# TVF with EF6 and WCF 5.6.3

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, entity-framework-6.1

I'm running into an exception when attempting to use Table Value Functions with Entity Framework 6.1.3 and WCF 5.6.3. End goal is to perform Restful queries against these TVFs, which return a result table back to the requester for further formatting. One question I do have is, do I need to also import the associated tables associated with the TVFs into the model?

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. 
The exception message is 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'. 
See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) 
at System.Data.Services.DataServiceConfiguration.InvokeStaticInitialization(Type type) 
at System.Data.Services.DataServiceConfiguration.Initialize(Type type) 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateConfiguration(Type dataServiceType, IDataServiceMetadataProvider provider, Boolean isInternallyCreatedProvider) 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

In the model's class, each corresponding TVF has a method:

```
    [DbFunction("MyEntities", "func_Info")]
    public virtual IQueryable<func_Info_Result> func_Info(string buildNumber)
    {
        var bNumberParameter = bNumber != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("bNumber", bNumber) :
            new ObjectParameter("bNumber", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<func_Info_Result>("[MyEntities].[func_Info](@bNumber)", bNumberParameter);
    }
```

And I'm calling it in the typical fashion in InitializeService, which is where the exception is generated:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("func_Info", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

EDIT: Inner Exception:

```
<Message>The given name 'func_Info' was not found in the entity sets.
```

Parameter name: name

Comment: what is in the server logs?

Comment: This is IIS Express, so what you see is what you get.

Comment: Not according to the error message....  It specifically says to see the logs for more details.  Without knowing what's in those logs, we can only make obscure wild guesses at what the problem might be.

Comment: We need to see the inner most error message to find out the root cause.

Comment: There is no further information. It hits the last line of code posted in the original post, and then exits with the exception from the VS debugger. @Claies - there is no further logging for this WCF project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose the core issue properly, it is necessary to see what is in the WCF Server Logs.  Add the following to the web.config for your WCF Service to specify the location that the WCF Logs are saved to, then generate the exception again.  Once you have captured the log of the error, you can open a new question with the results of the Invocation Exception.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "C:\Temp\SvcLog\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The `initializeData` attribute will set the location to which the logs will be saved.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! <Message>The given name 'func_Info' was not found in the entity sets.
Parameter name: name</Message>

Comment: Okay, I see the underlying issue -- TVFs aren't added to an Entity Set in the model. At this point, I'm unsure how to access TVFs from the WCF service. I really do not want to be accessing tables directly (which do get added to the Entity Set).